# Give circular background to textview using Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, android-custom-view, ondraw

> I want to draw a `textView` with **rounded border on Canvas**. So below code working fine. But circle require 15.0f to subtract from yPosCenter

How to properly give **circular background to textView perfectly in Canvas** . In my case I have to use a hard code figure 15.0f

```
                val verticalOffset = dayVerticalOffsets[day.indexOnMonthView]
                val xPos = x * dayWidth + horizontalOffset
                val yPos = y * dayHeight + verticalOffset
                val xPosCenter = xPos + dayWidth / 2
                val yPosCenter = yPos + dayHeight / 2


                //subtract 15.0f to adjust it to center - > How could I achieve it 
                //val subtractVal = yPosCenter - (paint.descent() + paint.ascent())// / 2
                canvas.drawCircle(xPosCenter,yPosCenter - 15.0f,paint.textSize * 0.85f , getCounterColor(day))
                canvas.drawText("15",xPosCenter,yPosCenter,getTextPaint(day))
```

What am I missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you are missing is that text won't be drawn vertically centered around `yPosCenter`:

```
// Outside draw function
private val textBounds = Rect()
...

val text = "15"

// Find the center of the text vertically
val textVerticalCenter = paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textBounds).exactCenterY()
canvas.drawText(text, xPosCenter, yPosCenter - textVerticalCenter, paint)
```